# Why can't an ISP ban access to a blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain, nodes, decentralization

I read that blockchain sits on top of the internet and is decentralised. We still have to access the blockchain network via an ISP. Without ISP, we can't access the internet so why can't an ISP block access to a blockchain network completely?

Many has talked about p2p but without ISP, how can we connect to other nodes? Isn't it an easy feat for an ISP to block blockchain?

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. However, that was in 2013 and now is the end of 2018. Is the answer still applicable?

Comment: Luckily not much of the P2P protocol has been changed in regards to it. The default ports are still the same, and Tor can still be used as an alternative. [This](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23846/banning-bitcoin-through-packet-filtering/23928#23928) thread also has some related information.